# .NET Data Grid with Combo Boxes - Is it possible with a single query?

Tags: .net, datagrid

I want to produce a data grid with combo boxes in it.  To use employees as an example, I want a grid that displays the employee name, date of hire, and positions held in the company.  Is it possible to write one query which results in the combo boxes and employee data or do you have to create the data grid with stub combo boxes and then use some client side scripting to populate the combo boxes or (I don't like this idea) have a stored procedure which produces the necessary HTML for each row.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely retrieve multiple result sets with a single query, what kind of Data Layer logic would you like to use?

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure shouldn't be generating HTML; generating HTML is a very procedural operation which any RDBMS is generally not good for.

Your stored procedure should return multiple result sets (or have multiple stored procedure calls).  The first would be the data set itself, with the keys to the relational data.

The subsequent result sets would be the sets of relational data which would be used for your drop downs.

Then, when building your HTML, you would render the grid from the primary result set and then populate the other combo boxes with the remaining result sets, performing lookups when rendering the initial selected value in the main grid.